# how to fetch gujrati font in php file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**php**

**set:-** **mysql_query("set names utf8");**

```
<?php 
    mysql_query("set names utf8");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT type_id, ji__type_name FROM tbl_stock_master");
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<option>'.$rs['type_name'].'</option>';
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a header on top of your page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

Like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8'); /*Add header here*/
    mysql_query("set names utf8");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT type_id, ji__type_name FROM tbl_stock_master");
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<option>'.$rs['type_name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Here, I assume that you have set utf8 in database for this.